# Mapeamento classes HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java, jee

Galera, tenho um dúvida sobre um exercício que foi passado na facul recentemente. Tenho que mapear classes com JPA, Hibernate e estou com um pouco de dificuldade na parte de mapear os relacionamentos dessas classes.

1. O problema é o seguinte, o exercício é sobre um Jogo de Futebol onde temos as classes Jogador, Time, Técnico, Juiz, Jogo.
2. No relacionamento ficaria Jogador possui um Time e o Time possui vários Jogadores. Até ai tudo bem!
3. Como mapiei este exemplo, e gostaria que vocês me ajudassem porque não estou conseguindo gerar o meu DB com esse mapeamento.

   Aqui é a classe Jogador onde referencio o Time dele.
   `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="time_Cod", insertable=true,updatable=true)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
   private Time time;`

   E meu Time que contém vários Jogadores.

   `@OneToMany(mappedBy="Time",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
   private ArrayList<Jogador> jogador;`
4. Há outros relacionamentos, mas, se eu botar aqui vocês acabariam fazendo minha atividade kkkk então só essa pequena ajuda já seria maravilhosa.
5. Se caso precisarem de mais informações, por favor me digam, e obrigado desde já!

EDIT- 1
Erro: `set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: conexaoDB
    ...]
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_testeAtvdAp02]
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
set 06, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
set 06, 2016 12:45:01 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Erro no cadastro: [PersistenceUnit: conexaoDB] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`

EDIT 2- Arquivo de Persintencia:

```
<persistence version="2.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="conexaoDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_testeAtvdAp02" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

EDIT 3 - Código

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {


        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("conexaoDB");
        factory.close();


      System.out.println("Gerado");     
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Não Gerado: "+e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Mande stacktrace do erro gerado e tente mudar o `mappedBy="Time"` para `mappedBy="time"`

Comment: Ok marcos, fiz a mudança que você disse e executei, porém ainda continuo com esse erro

Comment: ok, esse problema é em relação a sua configuração de conexão com o banco de dados, mais especificamente sua unidade de persistencia, poste seu arquivo de configuração (`persistence.xml`) e o código da fábrica de conexão @user54273

Comment: Ok Marcos, acabei de editar!

Comment: no seu `persistence.xml` falta vc adicionar suas entidades nas tags`<class> </class>`(Jogador, Time, Técnico, Juiz, Jogo) as que contem em seu código. não entendi por que vc declara usa fábrica em um método `main`, mas vc não tem que fecha-lo! apague:  `factory.close();`
e modifique `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>` por `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />` no `persistence.xml`

Comment: Marcos, em relação ao EntityManagerFactory eu coloquei ali por conta dos slides que foram passados, em relação a adicionar as entidades no meu persistence.xml eu não sabia dessa muito obrigado, eu ia ficar insistindo a vida toda em algo que não estava nem sabendo, agora vou em busca disso!

Comment: ok, vc só tem que publicar o fully qualified name da classe ex:  `<class>br.com.financas.modelo.Conta</class>` não esquece de falar se deu certo, pois acho que não é tudo.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou tentar e te dou retorno.

Comment: Agora estou recebendo um erro:
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.

Porém já alterei o tal provider e continuo com esse mesmo erro

Comment: pode crer, mas isso é só um aviso que seu provedor está obsoleto (seu código funcionou, apesar disto?)
use <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
`<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">` versão do `persistence.xml` e adicione o `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` isso tem a ver com a verão do Hibernate que estais usando. Note que a versão é do JPA2.1

Comment: Agora sim Marcos, obrigadão aê, você me salvou kk :) !

Comment: sério, cara?
só pra ajudar outras pessoas, irei postar isso como resposta e vc fecha a pergunta como encerrada, e marca a resposta como útil, blz?

Comment: Blz então, pode postar !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, no seu `persistence.xml` falta vc adicionar suas entidades nas `tags<class> </class>`, vc só tem que publicar o *fully qualified name* da classe ex: `<class>br.com.financas.modelo.Conta</class>`
no `persistence.xml`.

No seu caso dará um *warning* dizendo que seu *provider* é obsoleto, basta atualizar a configuração do `persistence.xml`, com o seguite *provider*:
Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
</persistence>`
```